# Where does Skype 5 for Linux keep user data?

Tags: skype, opensuse

I've just installed the latest Skype for Linux (version 5.0). In previous versions, Skype used to save the user data in `~/.skype` or `~/Skype`. It appears that in the latest version this has changed. Does anybody know where does the new version 5.0 of Skype keep the user data now?

Answer (score 0):

Check `~/.config/skypeforlinux/` (on Centos7, guess on suse should be similar).  Any way, I failed to push history from 4.x version, so also looking for ideas and details about new version.